fmincon Biasing one ouput and minimizing the objective Function
I have an inverse kinematics solver. I want to bias one joint angle value to at least approach a certain value wherein this angle will result in the link to be flat or parallel to the ground. The script runs well but my problem is fmincon stops the iteration, I think, once the default TolFun value is reached. The bias value is around +-0.17 radians or +- 10 degrees.
I've tried using a very small TolFun value such as 1e-12 but it when an iteration converges, the angle I want to bias still does is not reach the desired value or close to it. I tried adding an fval threshold and using while loop but I think the TolFun stopping criterion still supersedes that since whan I run the script, almost similar convergence are reached. I need some help in how to implement the biasing. Here is the code snippet:
function A = transformation_matrix(theta, alpha, a, d)
        A = [[cos(theta), -cos(alpha) * sin(theta), sin(alpha) * sin(theta), a * cos(theta)];
             [sin(theta), cos(alpha) * cos(theta), -sin(alpha) * cos(theta), a * sin(theta)];
             [0, sin(alpha), cos(alpha), d];
             [0, 0, 0, 1]];
    end

function position = forward_kinematics(joint_angles)
    theta2 = joint_angles(1);
    theta3 = joint_angles(2);
    theta4 = joint_angles(3);
    theta5 = joint_angles(4);
    theta6 = joint_angles(5);

    A1 = transformation_matrix(0, 0, 0, 148);
    A2 = transformation_matrix(theta2, pi/2, 0, 152);
    A3 = transformation_matrix(theta3, 0, 250, 0);
    A4 = transformation_matrix(theta4, 0, 160, 0);
    A5 = transformation_matrix(theta5+pi/2, pi/2, 0, 0);
    A6 = transformation_matrix(theta6, 0, -75, 160);

    position_matrix = A1 * A2 * A3 * A4 * A5 * A6 * [0; 0; 0; 1];
    %threshold = 1e-8;  % Small threshold to round off to zero
    %position_matrix(abs(position_matrix) < threshold) = 0;  % Set small values to zero
    position = position_matrix(1:3);
end

function error = objective_function(joint_angles, target, initial_guess, is_first_run)
    theta3 = joint_angles(2);
    theta4 = joint_angles(3);
    theta5 = -(theta3+theta4);

    position = forward_kinematics(joint_angles);
    error = norm(position - target);
    bias_theta5=abs(joint_angles(4)-theta5);
    disp('Theta 5 bias:');
    disp(bias_theta5);
    error += 1*bias_theta5 %bias to land theta5 close to a value that parallel with the origin Y-coord
    if ~is_first_run
        error += 0.1 * norm(joint_angles - initial_guess);  % Penalize deviation from initial guess
    end
end

function error = objective_function(joint_angles, target, initial_guess, is_first_run)
    theta3 = joint_angles(2);
    theta4 = joint_angles(3);
    theta5 = -(theta3 + theta4);

    position = forward_kinematics(joint_angles);
    error = norm(position - target);
    bias_theta5 = abs(joint_angles(4) - theta5);

    disp('Theta 5 bias:');
    disp(bias_theta5);

    error += 1 * bias_theta5;  % Bias to land theta5 close to the value parallel with the origin Y-coord

    if ~is_first_run
        error += 0.1 * norm(joint_angles - initial_guess);  % Penalize deviation from initial guess
    end
end

function [joint_angles, exitflag] = inverse_kinematics(target_position, initial_guess, is_first_run)
    options = optimset('Display', 'final', 'MaxIter', 2000);  % Omitting 'TolFun'

    % Constraints for initial values for the first four angles
    initial_lb = [-(5/6) * pi; -(1/6) * pi; -(11/18) * pi; -(1/2) * pi];
    initial_ub = [ (5/6) * pi;  (5/9) * pi;  0;           (1/2) * pi];

    if is_first_run
        lb = initial_lb;  % Use the initial lower bounds
        ub = initial_ub;  % Use the initial upper bounds
    else
        % Update bounds based on the converged joint angles
        lb = initial_lb - initial_guess(1:4);  % Subtract converged values
        ub = initial_ub - initial_guess(1:4);  % Subtract converged values
    end

    initial_guess_4 = initial_guess(1:4);
    %max_iter = 100;  % Set a maximum number of iterations
    fval_threshold = 0.17;  % Stopping criterion for fval
    iter = 0;
    converged = false;

    while ~converged %&& iter < max_iter
        % Optimize theta2, theta3, theta4
        [joint_angles_4, fval, exitflag] = fmincon(@(j) objective_function([j; 0], target_position, initial_guess, is_first_run), ...
                                                     initial_guess_4, [], [], [], [], lb, ub, [], options);

        % Check the stopping criterion based on fval
        if fval < fval_threshold
            converged = true;  % We have reached the desired fval
        end

        initial_guess_4 = joint_angles_4;  % Update initial guess for next iteration
        %iter = iter + 1;
    end

    joint_angles = [joint_angles_4; 0];  % Set theta 6 to zero

    % Display result
    if converged
        fprintf('Converged with fval: %f\n', fval);
    else
        fprintf('Maximum iterations reached without achieving desired fval.\n');
    end
end


Why have you set MaxIter to 2000? do you really know if below 2000 it has all converged?

Please supply a reproducible example. These functions are called from a script. That script would be helpful.

replace 'error += ..' with 'error=error+.. '
